# Misleading behavior when importing activities

Tags: import, activities

This is on CiviCRM 5.24.1, just installed. The behavior of the Import Activities page is odd. On the Preview page, Step 3 of 4, the buttons Previous, Import Now, or Cancel are displayed. However, no matter which button is selected, a popup box says: "Backing up your database before importing is recommended, as there is no Undo for this. Are you sure you want to import now?" Then the import appears to start and a progress bar appears, even if Previous or Cancel were selected. If Import Now was selected, the import proceeds normally. If Previous or Cancel was selected, nothing is imported, and it returns the user to Step 1 of 4. No harm is done, but the appearance that we are unable to stop the import regardless of the option selected is alarming to the user.

Comment: If you can reproduce it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org it sounds like it would be worth making a ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/user-interface/-/issues

Comment: Just crossreferencing for others. I assume you're the same person who added https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/user-interface/-/issues/17.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's me. :-)